# For how long is a Stripe card token valid?

Tags: stripe-payments

For approximately how long is a Stripe card token (aquired through Stripe.js) valid? [According to the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form#next-up):

> The token is single-use only and has a short life. Use it in an API
>   call immediately.

I understand I shouldn't store the token for use later, but how short is "short" in this case? Should I expect it to expire within seconds or minutes?

(Although not relevant to the question itself, the reason I'm asking is that I would like to take the token exchange step out of the transaction that the user is waiting for, and let a background job handle the actual Stripe integration. Obviously, that's not a good idea if the token has a *very* short lifetime.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The card token is valid for a few minutes (usually up to 10). What Stripe recommends in that case is to use the token now to create a customer via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) first to save its card and then let your background job handle the charge part after the fact.

This also ensures that the card is valid as Stripe runs a $0/$1 authorization on the card first. You can then give feedback to the customer immediately in case of an error.

Comment: how do we get the card list for each user

Comment: I have been using the same toke for more than a week now and its working lol

Comment: can you please mention the documentation to support your argument